# Remove Specific key value pair from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two key value pair arrays, one is the original, the other an array of key value pairs that need to be removed. I need to remove a specific combination, ie $removeArray would contain:

```
Array([Word] => 78)
```

I've tried:

```
foreach($removeArray as $key => $value){unset($originalArray[$key][$value]);}
```

This doesn't work at all. **I need to remove based off an exact key value pair match.**

---

**EDIT:**

Original

```
Array ( [distribution] => 25 [watch] => 25 [electricity] => 25 [timepiece] => 8 [wristwatch] => 25 [energy] => 8 [transmission] => 8 [clock] => 16 )
```

Remove

```
Array ( [timepiece] => 8 [energy] => 8 [watch] => 17 )
```

Result

```
Array ( [distribution] => 25 [watch] => 25 [electricity] => 25 [wristwatch] => 25  [transmission] => 8 [clock] => 16 )
```

---

NOTE:

`[watch] => 25` is not affected, because it is not equal to `[watch] => 17`

Comment: Can you post two array and expected result ?

Comment: if($key == "Word"){unset($originalArray[$key][$value]);}

Comment: Posted example arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_diff_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) for that, that compares both the values and the keys:

```
$result = array_diff_assoc($original, $to_remove);
```

Example code:

```
$removeArray = array(
    'word'=>45,
    'number'=>112,
    'sign'=>2167
);

$originalArray = array(
    'lorem'=>2343,
    'ipsum'=>433,
    'word'=>78,
    'number'=>112,
    'sign'=>2167
);

$result = array_diff_assoc($originalArray, $removeArray);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [lorem] => 2343
    [ipsum] => 433
    [word] => 78
)
```

Comment: Bingo! Not sure how efficient it is, but it's the simplest answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach($removeArray as $key => $value){
    if($value==$originalArray[$key])
        unset($originalArray[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like:

```
if($originalArray[$key] == "78" && $key = "Word") {
unset($originalArray[$key]);
}
```